# Reflecting ASMX via WSDL, with custom types

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, reflection, wsdl

I need to reflect an ASMX web service via WSDL.
Simple cases go all fine, using the accepted answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208636/how-to-use-reflection-in-c-sharp-to-list-the-methods-of-an-asmx).
But then I have some complex type (a strong-typed dataset) defined in there.
The original source of the service looks like

```
[WebMethod]
public int GetCustomer(string civicRegistrationNo, out MyCompany.E_WebServices.DataSets.CustomerDataSet customerDS)
```

This `CustomerDataSet` gives me trouble, because in the reflection the method comes as

```
GetCustomer [Int32]: civicRegistrationNo [String], customerDS [out XmlElement]
```

whereas what I would like to see (and what comes out if I reflect the DLL directly) is

```
GetCustomer [Int32]: civicRegistrationNo [String], customerDS [out CustomerDataSet]
```

How should I improve my code (below) to get the type `CustomerDataSet` coming correctly (not as `XmlElement`)?
Sure it has something to do with this block in the WSDL

```
<s:import namespace="http://tempuri.org/CustomerDataSet.xsd"/>
<s:import schemaLocation="http://localhost/E-WebServices/WSCustomer.asmx?schema=CustomerDataSet" namespace="http://tempuri.org/CustomerDataSet.xsd"/>
```

and yes I can see that definition in the browser if I open

```
http://localhost/E-WebServices/WSCustomer.asmx?schema=CustomerDataSet
```

But how to get it coming from this code below?

```
var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
var stream = client.OpenRead("http://localhost/E-WebServices/WSCustomer.asmx?wsdl");
var description = ServiceDescription.Read(stream);
var importer = new ServiceDescriptionImporter();
importer.ProtocolName = "Soap12";
importer.AddServiceDescription(description, null, null);
importer.Style = ServiceDescriptionImportStyle.Client;
importer.CodeGenerationOptions = CodeGenerationOptions.GenerateProperties;
var nmspace = new CodeNamespace();
var unit1 = new CodeCompileUnit();
unit1.Namespaces.Add(nmspace);
var warning = importer.Import(nmspace, unit1);
if (warning == 0)
{
    CodeDomProvider provider1 = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
    string[] assemblyReferences = new string[5] { "System.dll", "System.Web.Services.dll", "System.Web.dll", "System.Xml.dll", "System.Data.dll" };
    CompilerParameters parms = new CompilerParameters(assemblyReferences);
    CompilerResults results = provider1.CompileAssemblyFromDom(parms, unit1);
    if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (CompilerError oops in results.Errors)
            Debug.WriteLine(oops.ErrorText);
        throw new Exception("Compile Error Occured calling webservice");
    }
    object service = results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("WSCustomer");
    List<MethodInfo> methods = service.GetType().GetMethods().ToList();
    // use them somehow
}
```

I am kind of inspired by what Visual Studio does itself - if web ref is added, it only has the WSDL (it doesn't go directly to that DLL even if it's in the same machine, I think), and yet it can derive the included type nicely. So I figure it must be possible!?
[image]

Comment: In order to use a data type as part of a SOAP message, it must have some kind of XML equivalent. AFAIK, DataSet does not have such an  equivalent. You need to use a different data type to transfer your data across a SOAP message.

Comment: Web services should be interoperable. Even if this was technically possible, I would opt for using DTOs instead. Then you can create objects that are better serialized to soap and are easier to use on the other side as well.

Comment: Thanks @elad, but the service structure is not under my control (even as I have the code). I also added some VS screenshot to my question, about why I think it shouldn't be that abnormal what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: BTW did you realize that ASMX is a legacy technology that should not be used for new development?

Comment: There are ways around this (like creating an extension method to the `DataSet` class, which will serialize it to XML manually), but not everything that is technically possible should be done.

Comment: Maybe this can help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s5xy331f(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: @john: yes, I understand perfectly ASMX is a legacy, but unfortunately my client company won't request a change anytime soon. Elad: will look into the link, thanks. But again, the service itself works fine (including sending typed datasets back and forth). I only need the **reflection** (MethodInfos etc in C#), created dynamically out of WSDL

Comment: WSDL does not have any information about methods. It only holds the properties! Maybe you can explain what it is you are trying to do...

Comment: Thanks everybody, I got it coming (somehow, at least), posting answer to myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it seems I got it working (maybe not the cleanest way)

```
string serviceUrl = "http://localhost/E-WebServices/WSCustomer.asmx";
var client = new WebClient();
ServiceDescription descr;
using (var stream = client.OpenRead(serviceUrl + "?wsdl"))
{
    descr = ServiceDescription.Read(stream);
}
var importer = new ServiceDescriptionImporter()
{
    ProtocolName = "Soap12",
    Style = ServiceDescriptionImportStyle.Client,
    CodeGenerationOptions = CodeGenerationOptions.GenerateProperties,
};
importer.AddServiceDescription(descr, null, null);
// Add any imported schemas
var importedSchemas = new List<string>();
foreach (XmlSchema wsdlSchema in descr.Types.Schemas)
{
    foreach (XmlSchemaObject externalSchema in wsdlSchema.Includes)
    {
        if (externalSchema is XmlSchemaImport)
        {
            XmlSchemaImport schemaImport = externalSchema as XmlSchemaImport;
            var split = schemaImport.Namespace.Split(new char[] { '/', '.' });
            string schemaId = split[split.Count() - 2];
            if (importedSchemas.Contains(schemaId))
                continue;
            importedSchemas.Add(schemaId);
            Uri schemaUri = new Uri(serviceUrl + "?schema=" + schemaId);
            XmlSchema schema;
            using (var wsdlStream = client.OpenRead(schemaUri))
            {
                schema = XmlSchema.Read(wsdlStream, null);
            }
            importer.Schemas.Add(schema);
        }
    }
}
var nmspace = new CodeNamespace();
var unit1 = new CodeCompileUnit();
unit1.Namespaces.Add(nmspace);
var warning = importer.Import(nmspace, unit1);
if (warning == 0)
{
    CodeDomProvider provider1 = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("CSharp");
    string[] assemblyReferences = new string[5] { "System.dll", "System.Web.Services.dll", "System.Web.dll", "System.Xml.dll", "System.Data.dll" };
    CompilerParameters parms = new CompilerParameters(assemblyReferences);
    CompilerResults results = provider1.CompileAssemblyFromDom(parms, unit1);
    if (results.Errors.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (CompilerError oops in results.Errors)
            Debug.WriteLine(oops.ErrorText);
        throw new Exception("Compile Error Occured calling webservice");
    }
    object service = results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance("WSCustomer");
    Type t = service.GetType();
    List<MethodInfo> methods = t.GetMethods().ToList();
    // use them somehow
}
```